# Visual Studio 2010 is instrumenting all of my assemblies during code coverage and I don't want it to

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have ten projects within my Visual Studio solution.  One of them is an MVC 3 project and one is an Azure project.

I have chosen five projects to instrument for code coverage.

When I view the code coverage results--it is instrumenting all nine code projects (including the unit test projects) and therefore my total coverage % is incorrect?!

When I de-select the MVC project for instrumentation, it properly instruments the remaining four assemblies.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to resolve this issue--however, I don't quite understand the root cause.

In the .testsettings file, in the Code Coverage Detail dialog box, I had the five projects selected.  One of them, by defualt, was the Web project which defaulted to \Web.  I unchecked this item, and manually added the Web assembly--which resides in \Web/bin.

This addressed the issue and only the proper assemblies are instrumented.